Increase penalty withing citation using biblatex, avoid linebreaking at citations, not forced (without the use of \mbox)
I am currently using biblatex and try to write and adjust the citations styles to my liking/need. Since citing in law might not always be appealing to the eye I would like to keep the citation itself not between two line if possible. emphasis on if possible, I dont want forced adjustments to the citation command since some citations can be quite lengthy resulting in big whitespaces between multiple citations. Ideally I want to increase the badness (\penalty) for just a specific section. The rest I think I can adjust myself and add to the citation command. Currently I am using \mbox on specific sections of my citations where I really want to avoid a broken line:
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{jurisdiction}{%
\usebibmacro{bibindex}%
\usebibmacro{begentry}%
%\usebibmacro{author/editor}%
\printnames[nonitalic]{author}%
%\printlist{institution}% no idea
\setunit{\addspace}%
\iffieldundef{officialvolume}{\usebibmacro{date}\printfield{chamber}\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}{}%
%\setunit{\addspace}%
\printfield{sign}%
\setunit{\addspace}%
\iffieldundef{officialvolume}{}{**\mbox{**\printfield{officialcollection}\addspace\printfield{officialvolume}}}%
\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}
\iffieldequalstr{namehash}{191bb1ac025d7a8c78612adbbc8fb556}{\printfield{decision}}{}%looked up the namehash for EGMR since field author cannot be tested
%\mkbibemph{\usebibmacro{title}}%
\usebibmacro{finentry}}


This is not ideal what I need is a command instead of \mbox wrapped around the whole citation (to be implemented on all citations, \mbox is bigfatugly) that is less forcefull, but still tries to avoid a breakup of the citation. It would make the citations more readable.
It should work something like that (dont know if that code here works at all, but its at least illustrative)
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\**magicalpeanaltyincrasingcode_thatisnotmbox**{\oldcite{#1}}}

Please avoid the use of packages, this problem does not need biblatex etc to be resolved since it should work on any section of text

you could edit the question. You have provided a chunk of biblatex code but say you want a general non-biblatex answer. It is not clear what answer you want, there is no general penalty for a run of text. There are the penalties for hyphenation which you could increase but if you want to add penalties at inter-word spaces you need to add a penalty  explicitly before each space.  So if your text is generated by biblatex any answer will be all about modifying biblatex commands to add those penalties. You should provide an example document with a bad break to allow people to test answers.
